# SQL Server database diagram practice

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am making a database diagram using SQL Server 2014 and in my database I have foreign keys constrains that respectively are shown on the diagram (auto generated by the studio). The keys don't point exactly from the column to the column that the constraint is made on. So my question is if I should move them a little (to the exact column) and if this is a good practice or no?

Answer (score 0):

This is not a good practice.  Microsoft's diagrams are not an exact science when it comes to foreign keys.  If you move them to exactly correspond, and then someone bumps them later, you could be thinking they point to the wrong column.

A better practice is to name them the same in both tables, or closely enough that you can tell at a glance.  Don't think of the diagrams as a machine--just a blueprint.